# Control app launching on Android

Tags: android, password-protection

I want to build an Android app that protects particular app with some mechanism of protection, something like password. I was searching over Internet how to achieve to control app launching on Android, but I couldn't find an answer.

I want that on particular app start, user gets view on which he needs to type, for example some password.

Comment: im not sure if i am getting this... you want to write a app, which "protects" other apps, so you can only start those other apps with a password?

Comment: Something like this...http://droidlessons.com/how-to-password-protect-apps-on-android/

Comment: i would have said it aint possible, but since it obviously is i cant help... very intresting question therefore...

Comment: did you find out something? i so, would be nice if you post an answer yourself, i'd like to know how this can be done.

Comment: @user232343  can u pls share your knowledge how u have done  /?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have an start activity which ask for username password etc..by matching it with database you can start new activity or you can close app on mismatch.

Comment: OP wants to protect other apps, now his own